# Why getting out of memory exception when trying to play images in pictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Player_Manager
{
    public partial class ScreenShotsPlayer : Form
    {
        FileInfo[] images;
        DirectoryInfo di1;
        int current = 0;

        public ScreenShotsPlayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            di1 = new DirectoryInfo(@"e:\screenshots");
            images = di1.GetFiles("*.bmp");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            current = (current >= images.Length - 1) ? 0 : ++current;
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(images[current].FullName);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

There are 1200 images on the hard disk and the timer is set to 100ms.
After about 258-270 images played it's throwing the out of memory exception on the line:

```
pictureBox1.Refresh();

System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Out of memory.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect)
       at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

If i will remove the line pictureBox1.Refresh();
Then it will throw the exception on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Player_Manager
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

On the line Application.Run(new Form1());

Same exception.

Comment: This is not a `C` question. This is a `C#` question.

Comment: Do not use a C tag for obviously non-C languages. Hint: "Python" and "Pascal" both start with "T", but one would not tag a Python question with a Pascal tag.

Comment: Yes my mistake sorry i meant to tag it as c# not c

Comment: I just needed to add in the timer1 tick event in the bottom: pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();

Comment: I specifically didn't write that because if the system triggers a `WM_PAINT` and the `Image` control tries to redraw itself, it'll throw an exception because it tries to access a disposed object. Remember this isn't 1980, you're not in complete control of the customer's computers. Anything can happen without your deciding it needs to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the thing with GDI+ is that the memory it uses isn't managed -- the GC has no clue how much you're wasting to trigger a collection, so it just piles on and on until GDI+ runs out of allocatable memory.

The fix is pretty trivial. You know the bitmaps you're allocating, simply dispose of them when they're no longer needed:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(pictureBox1.Image!=null)
        {
            var img = pictureBox1.Image;  // cache it to dispose
            pictureBox1.Image = null;     // don't dispose an used object
            img.Dispose();                // and dispose of it
        }

        current = (current >= images.Length - 1) ? 0 : ++current;
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(images[current].FullName);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you "cache it to dispose", but you never do anything with the *var img*?